# Install Dependencies again for new React Project

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, frontend

I was working on a React Project and I successfully completed it. Now I started working on another project. Do I need to install these dependencies again or how can I inject dependencies and start work on my new React Project?

Let me know if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies might vary across your various projects. npm packages installed with global flag reside on the system. You will need to install the required dependencies for your new project.

Alernatively, if you are going to use the same dependencies again, just copy the contents of package.json from old project to package.json of new project and run

```
npm install
```

or

```
yarn
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

if you copy over your package.json you'll have the same node_modules you have used in your previous project, so copy over the package.json and edit the fields that are specific to your new project (dependencies and devdependencies are the ones that will be installed) and do

```
npm i or yarn
```

These commands will generate the real node_modules declared by your package.json.

whatever you prefer, thought i'd give you some more explanation so you know how this process works.

Feel free to hit me up if you got questions :) good luck coding.

Answer (score 0):

You should you npm link to add a global module to your local projects.

Answer (score 0):

If your dependencies are same as your previous folder you can copy the package.json file with its content to your current project folder and then run:
**npm start**   in your therminal.

Otherwise, you have to install all of your required dependencies separately.

Answer (score 0):

Just build a starter app with all the dependencies you're most likely to be using again. Then add it to a git repo and simply clone it every time you want to start a new project. You can use different branches for projects that have different dependencies and complexity. It's a really quick way to get off the ground with a new project.